# I have a DataFrame and need to perform calculations between columns. Can my function do_something be vectorised?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization

I have a DataFrame and need to perform calculations between columns. Can my function `do_something` be vectorised ?

Column `['1min', '2min', '5min', '15min', '30min', '1hour', '2hour', '4hour', '1day', '2day', '7day',]` need to be compared with price and the value of the previous column in turn. If the column is less than `price` and smaller than the `previous column`, `min_sig` is assigned the value of the column, and `min_bar` is assigned the name of the column. If it `does not match`, if it is the column '1min', then `min_sig` and `min_bar` are assigned the values `False`, and the other columns `interrupt` the loop.

My code can achieve the effect I want, can the function `generate_data()` be optimized by vectorization?

My code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def generate_data():
    code = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
    price = [72, 50.8, 77.8, 54.6]
    min1 = [69.78, 49.21, 79.75, 56.21]
    min2 = [69.9, 49.22, 79.4, 55.85]
    min5 = [73.36, 51.81, 74.78, 52]
    min15 = [79.07, 56.25, 67.86, 46.9]
    min30 = [77.1, 54.86, 70.38, 48.91]
    hour1 = [75.12, 53.49, 72.84, 51.29]
    hour2 = [74.1, 52.75, 73.51, 51.79]
    hour4 = [72.18, 51.69, 77.83, 55.96]
    day1 = [78.13, 56.76, 73.47, 52.37]
    day2 = [80.42, 58.72, 71.88, 51.78]
    day7 = [110.79, 84.6, 83.73, 65.48]
    dict1 = {'code': code, 'price': price, '1min': min1, '2min': min2, '5min': min5, '15min': min15, '30min': min30,
             '1hour': hour1, '2hour': hour2, '4hour': hour4, '1day': day1, '2day': day2, '7day': day7, }
    df = pd.DataFrame(dict1)
    df['min_bar'] = np.NAN
    df['min_sig'] = np.NAN
    col = ['code', 'price', 'min_bar', 'min_sig', '1min', '2min', '5min', '15min', '30min', '1hour', '2hour', '4hour',
           '1day', '2day', '7day', ]
    df = df[col]
    return df


def do_something(a):
    list1 = ['1min', '2min', '5min', '15min', '30min', '1hour', '2hour', '4hour',
             '1day', '2day', '7day', ]
    for i in range(len(list1)):
        bar = list1[i]
        if i == 0:
            if a['price'] >= a[bar]:
                a['min_sig'] = a[bar]
                a['min_bar'] = bar
            else:
                a['min_sig'] = False
                a['min_bar'] = False
                break
        else:
            if a['min_sig'] >= a[bar]:
                a['min_sig'] = a[bar]
                a['min_bar'] = bar
            else:
                break
    return a


def main():
    df = generate_data()
    print('Dataframe before running generate_data():')
    print(df)
    df = df.apply(do_something, axis=1)
    print('The result after running is the result I want:')
    print(df)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

```
Dataframe before running generate_data():
  code  price  min_bar  min_sig   1min  ...  2hour  4hour   1day   2day    7day
0    a   72.0      NaN      NaN  69.78  ...  74.10  72.18  78.13  80.42  110.79
1    b   50.8      NaN      NaN  49.21  ...  52.75  51.69  56.76  58.72   84.60
2    c   77.8      NaN      NaN  79.75  ...  73.51  77.83  73.47  71.88   83.73
3    d   54.6      NaN      NaN  56.21  ...  51.79  55.96  52.37  51.78   65.48

[4 rows x 15 columns]
The result after running is the result I want:
  code  price min_bar min_sig   1min  ...  2hour  4hour   1day   2day    7day
0    a   72.0    1min   69.78  69.78  ...  74.10  72.18  78.13  80.42  110.79
1    b   50.8    1min   49.21  49.21  ...  52.75  51.69  56.76  58.72   84.60
2    c   77.8   False   False  79.75  ...  73.51  77.83  73.47  71.88   83.73
3    d   54.6   False   False  56.21  ...  51.79  55.96  52.37  51.78   65.48

[4 rows x 15 columns]
```

```
%timeit df.apply(do_something,axis=1)
4.88 ms ± 50.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: Do you mean vectorised not serialised?

Comment: @HenryEcker Yes,vectoried not serialised. And I revised the related words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, it looks like you want to get the `idxmin` and `min` masked with False if the first value is not greater than price.

You can use numpy to get both operations at once:

```
m = np.argmin(df[list1].values, axis=1)
(pd.DataFrame({'min_bar':  np.take(list1, m),
               'min_sig':  np.take(df[list1].values, m)})
   .mask(df['price'].lt(df[list1[0]]), False)
)
```

(Then join or assign to the original df)

Output:

```
  min_bar min_sig
0    1min   69.78
1    1min   69.78
2   False   False
3   False   False
```

##### using pandas

This requires searching for the min twice, though

```
m = df['price'].lt(df[list1[0]])

df['min_bar'] = df[list1].idxmin(axis=1).mask(m, False)
df['min_sig'] = df[list1].min(axis=1).mask(m, False)
```